# How can the method of complex exponentials be used to find a complex solution i(t) which varies harmonically in time.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am WEAK in DE's.  I have been trying to understand this question all day.  I posted the question as an image since I don't have enough rep points to post it here.

http://images.4chan.org/sci/src/1327448267650.jpg

There is one example in my text Butkov on how to do this but it is not clear at all to me what I must do!

so far I just wrote:

$$L i''(t) + R i'(t) + (1/C) i(t) = - V_o \omega \sin(\omega t)$$
I then took a function $f(t) = Fe^{it}$

where $F = V_o\omega$, and so $Fe^{i*t} = V_o\omega(\cos(\omega t) - i\sin(\omega t))$

I then wrote $\Im(V_o\omega e^{-it}) = -V_o \omega \sin ( \omega t)$

I clearly have no idea what I am doing.  Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The link isn't working for me.

Comment: My apologies.  I reposted it on Photobucket.  Perhaps this website restricts certain urls.

http://s560.photobucket.com/albums/ss45/SnoopyRedBaron/?action=view&current=monsterproblem.jpg#!oZZ1QQcurrentZZhttp%3A%2F%2Fs560.photobucket.com%2Falbums%2Fss45%2FSnoopyRedBaron%2F%3Faction%3Dview%26current%3Dmonsterproblem.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve the differential equation $L i''(t) + R i'(t) + (1/C) i(t) = - V_o \omega \sin(\omega t)$.  The right side is the imaginary part of 
$- V_o \omega e^{i\omega t}$, so the idea is to first find a solution of the differential equation with right side replaced by $-V_o \omega e^{i\omega t}$, and the imaginary part of that solution will be a solution of your differential equation.  Try a solution of the form $y(t) = A e^{i\omega t}$: plug this in to the (new) differential equation, and see if you can find a complex constant $A$ that makes the equation true.